# Accessing network drives is too slow

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, network-shares

I had Windows 10 on my client machine and just made a fresh new installation. The server is a Linux machine where I did not change anything.

Since I made the fresh installation of Windows 10, I have troubles accessing my network drives. It takes up to 1 minute until the explorer windows loaded the content of the drive. It is not, that the drive just needs to start. I had this before as well and usually takes 3-5 seconds and not only one minute. I can also here it, when it starts ^^

A problem which I identified is, that even the windows of "My computer" is not showing the "used disc space" of the drives. When this is loaded, I can usually access the drives immediately. But after a couple of minutes doing nothing, I need to wait again that long.

The green bar in the explorer showing as well and I always have to wait until it's done.

Picture 1: "My Computer" while the network drives are not loaded
[image: "My Computer" while the network drives are not loaded]
Picture 2: "My Computer" when the network drives are loaded and I can access them
[image: "My Computer" when the network drives are loaded and I can access them]
Does anyone know why this is happening? I went fine before I reinstalled the windows.

Comment: I have the same problem and have not been able to find what is causing this. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Many people point to Windows caching as the problem.  You can turn off the caching by changing the registry keys below.  You can create and run a `.reg` file with the following contents or manually editing the settings in `regedit`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters]
"DirectoryCacheLifetime"=dword:0
"FileInfoCacheLifetime"=dword:0
"FileNotFoundCacheLifetime"=dword:0
```

And FYI the defaults are:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters]
"DirectoryCacheLifetime"=dword:10
"FileInfoCacheLifetime"=dword:10
"FileNotFoundCacheLifetime"=dword:5
```

From https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/ff686200(v=ws.10)

Comment: Has anyone experienced any benefits from this? I think this article may be a little out-dated

Comment: I have tried this but no luck still.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try:

Remove Remote Different Compression.

1. Press the Windows key on the keyboard.
2. Type "Turn Windows features on or off" without quotes in the search box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Remove the check mark next to "Remote Differential Compression".

Clear DNS Cache.

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, click or tap Command Prompt (Administrator).
2. Type the command `ipconfig /flushdns` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Also this registry fix might do the trick:

Regedit

- Search for Key:

  ```
  HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
  ```
- Add:

  ```
  DirectoryCacheLifetime Dword=0
  FileInfoCacheLifetime Dword=0 
  FileNotFoundCacheLifetime Dword=0
  ```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer this link for list of possible steps you can do . 
https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/creating-folders-or-accessing-files-on-remote-computer-is-very-slow/

Comment: Welcome to superuser. On Stackexchange, we want complete answers, and links only as reference.